# Javascript - Changing content for input element which has no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am working with Weebly as a CMS for one of my clients. I am having to change the content for an input field however by default it has no value. The code for the input is as follows

```
<input class="wsite-form-input name="apply-code" placeholder="Enter Code">
```

I am trying to change the content of this with some JavaScript but not sure about the best way to go about this. I would normally just create a variable and then change the value of that variable but seeing as there isn't one present I don't think I can do it.

Could I change the inner text?

Thanks

Comment: `$("input[name=apply-code]").val();`?

Comment: All you need : $("input[name="apply-code"]).val("New Text"). You can't change innerHtml for input types. Also, this would only work if you have name=apply-code unique to that field.

Comment: @DinoMyte Ok I will give it a go

Comment: @dwinnbrown one double inverted quote is missing after class please note that

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing a closing apostroph after `.wsite-form-input`, and to give it a value, you could do the following:

`$(".wsite-form-input").val("Your value here");`

Comment: This would change the text of all input controls having class wsite_form_input.

Comment: @DinoMyte there is a more specific class for the input that I can apply it to "wsite-coupon-input" so I think this should work

Comment: Please mark as answered if this answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily change the input element's value as like this

```js
var name="Put your name here";
$('input.wsite-form-input').val(name);
```

[here is demo work](https://jsfiddle.net/kkwrcm7c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, something like:

```
function changeInputValue(textValue){
 document.getElementsByName("apply-code")[0].value=textValue;
 }
```